# Display all available WIFI connections with Swift in OS X

Tags: swift, macos, swift2, corewlan

I'm trying to display all available WIFI connections. It doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreWLAN

var cwInterface = CWInterface()

do {
    let routers = try cwInterface.scanForNetworksWithSSID(nil)
    print(routers)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I don't get any result. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you initialize CWInterface with an interface name, like "en1".

But it's better to not use harcoded names, so we'll also use `CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient().interface()` which returns the default WIFI interface.

Example of a class to manage all this:

```
class Discovery {

    var currentInterface: CWInterface
    var interfacesNames: [String] = []
    var networks: Set<CWNetwork> = []

    // Failable init using default interface
    init?() {
        if let defaultInterface = CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient().interface(),
               name = defaultInterface.interfaceName {
            self.currentInterface = defaultInterface
            self.interfacesNames.append(name)
            self.findNetworks()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    // Init with the literal interface name, like "en1"
    init(interfaceWithName name: String) {
        self.currentInterface = CWInterface(interfaceName: name)
        self.interfacesNames.append(name)
        self.findNetworks()
    }

    // Fetch detectable WIFI networks
   func findNetworks() {
        do {
            self.networks = try currentInterface.scanForNetworksWithSSID(nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

}
```

Call it with the default interface:

```
if let discovery = Discovery() {
    print(discovery.networks)
    for network in discovery.networks {
        print(network.ssid!)
    }
}
```

Or with an interface name:

```
let discovery = Discovery(interfaceWithName: "en1")
let results = discovery.networks
```

Results contains all the scanned networks:

> `[<CWNetwork: 0x608000001bd0> [ssid=SomeNetworkName, bssid=xxxx, security=WPA Enterprise, rssi=xx, channel=<CWChannel: 0x600000004fb0> [channelNumber=11(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}], ibss=0], etc]`

Comment: use let names = CWWiFiClient.interfaceNames() or ( deprecated now let names_old = CWInterface.interfaceNames() ) which gives you set of available interface names (i agree, that "en1" will be most probably the only value in the set, but i try to avoid 'wired" names at all)

Comment: i use let interface = CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient().interface() which gives me 'default' bounded interface ( yes, usually the same as CWInterface(name: "en1") ).

Comment: @user3441734 Again, a very useful comment. I've added this to my answer for a default initializer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @user3441734 "en1" is only the default name for the Wi-FI interface on systems that have a single built-in ethernet (like an iMac) on the MacBook Air, MacBook or any other device without ethernet, Wi-Fi is "en0"

Comment: Really helpful. Any idea about How to connect the WIFI using SSID and Password?