# Getting list of preferred wifi networks on Mac with Swift 3

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way to get the list of preferred ( = saved) wifi's ssid on MacOS with Swift 3.0 ?

I found some example which are deprecated and are (surprisingly) only runnable on iOS.

[image: Network Preferences]

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35806639/2227743) should help you - I suppose you can find the preferred/saved ones in the list by parsing the results.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your solution seems to provide the currently available networks. I want to get the ones the computer got connected to during its lifetime.

Comment: You're right. I thought the list would include them but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred Networks are stored in a plist as part of System Preferences `NSUserDefaults`.  While I don't see an API to access these names directly, you can use the `defaults` shell command or `NSTask` to access the values:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences | grep SSIDString
```

Note that in this list are not only all of the SSIDs that the computer has connected to, but the list synced with any iCloud-enabled device.

Related discussion here: [OS X Daily - See a List of All Wi-Fi Networks a Mac Has Previously Connected To](http://osxdaily.com/2012/12/21/list-wi-fi-networks-mac-has-connected-to-before/)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most beautiful code ever, but it works in Swift 3.0.

```
func shell(arguments: [String] = []) -> (String? , Int32) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    let terminationStatus = task.terminationStatus
    return (output, terminationStatus)
}
```

Extensions:

```
extension String {
    func stringByReplacingFirstOccurrenceOfString(
        target: String, withString replaceString: String) -> String
    {
        if let range = self.range(of: target) {
            return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replaceString)
        }
        return self
    }
}

extension String {
    func stringByReplacingLastOccurrenceOfString(
        target: String, withString replaceString: String) -> String
    {
        if let range = self.range(of: target, options: String.CompareOptions.backwards) {
            return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replaceString)
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Get and clean the wifi's SSIDs

```
let (output, terminationStatus) = shell(arguments: ["-c", "defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences | grep SSIDString"])
    if (terminationStatus == 0) {
        let arrayOfWifi = output?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)

        for var aWifi in arrayOfWifi! {
            aWifi = aWifi.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            if (aWifi.hasPrefix("SSIDString = ")) {
                aWifi = aWifi.stringByReplacingFirstOccurrenceOfString(target: "SSIDString = ", withString: "")
            }
            if (aWifi.hasPrefix("\"")) {
                aWifi = aWifi.stringByReplacingFirstOccurrenceOfString(target: "\"", withString: "")
            }
            if (aWifi.hasSuffix("\";")) {
                aWifi = aWifi.stringByReplacingLastOccurrenceOfString(target: "\";", withString: "")
            }
            if (aWifi.hasSuffix(";")) {
                aWifi = aWifi.stringByReplacingLastOccurrenceOfString(target: ";", withString: "")
            }
            aWifi = aWifi.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            print(aWifi)
        }
    }
}
```