# Trigger My app from Background when system event occurs : Macos

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I'm new to Macos app development, Is there a way to trigger my app from the background when the user connects to a particular wifi network in Macos like this: 
[Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7m22.png)

I researched about it and learnt it could be done with reachability but could not figure it out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want exactly, show a notification when the Mac connects to a specific network? It's not super clear, please explain. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EricAya ,Yes I want to show a notification when the Mac connects to a specific network.

Comment: With the Reachability library by Ashley Mills you should be able to do it. Here's a quick outline of what you could do. Look [here](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift#example---notifications) for an example of using the reachability notifier. Once reachabilityChanged is called because a network change happened, parse the object to find if a network was just joined and which one. Once you get the info, you can post your own user notification.

Comment: My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35806639/2227743) could also help, in a way, if you need to list the available networks then compare the list with the new one once reachabilityChanged has been called. I don't know - you will tell us what worked once you've tried. :)